# intertext with flalign in LyX Version 2.2.2

Tags: math-mode, equations, lyx

I want to use `\intertext` with `flalign` in `LyX Version 2.2.2`. I have the following `tex` document. When I import this `tex` document to `LyX Version 2.2.2`, it does not work import correctly. Any help to  use `\intertext` with `flalign` in `LyX Version 2.2.2` will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  && f &= ma;&\\
\text{or} && f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};&\\
\text{or}  &&f &= m  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

**Edited**

From `LYX` Math Manual

> As `LYX` doesn’t yet support `\intertext` directly, the text is
>   written as mathematical text. `\intertext` must hereby be at the
>   beginning of a line and appears in the output above this line.

Comment: I know it's not ideal, but maybe just use ERT? Also file an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac (choose the "mathed" component).

Comment: Does the intertext have to be on the same lines as the formulae, or in between?

Comment: Note that both flalign and intertext are discussed in LyX's math manual. See Help > Math for more information. I think the main problem might be *importing* this .tex code into LyX. But there should be a way to do the same thing from within LyX.

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for your comments and showing interest in my problem. I would highly appreciate if you guide me how to use `flalign` and `intertext` in `LyX`. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 sorry I don't have the time (and I don't know. I would have to learn how to do it myself first). I hope the Math manual gives some good ideas.

Comment: @scottkosty: Extract from `LYX` Math Manual: As `LYX` doesn’t yet support `\intertext` directly, the text is written as mathematical text. `\intertext` must hereby be at the beginning of a line and appears in the output above this line.

Comment: @MYaseen208 don't forget you can answer your own question. Maybe you can say to either use ERT or \intertext must be at the beginning?

Comment: Instead of answering in the question, why don't you write up a proper answer. That might make it useful for others seeing the question.

Comment: Note that a fix has been provided and might be included in 2.3.1 and/or 2.2.4: https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/23766fdd592b/lyxgit